# Why is grouping by dates in a Pandas dataframe so slow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to perform a `groupby` on a Pandas data frame but it is extremely slow for date types.  In this example I see the run time as 10x longer when group by a `date` compared to an `int`, even though no operation is being performed on the data.

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

d = dt.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
dates = [d for x in range(1,1500000)]
ints = [1 for x in range(1,1500000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'int': ints})

# This takes about 10 seconds
df.groupby(by=[df.date.map(lambda x: x)])
# This takes about 1 second
df.groupby(by=[df.int.map(lambda x: x)])
```

Comment: Why are you doing a map ? This seems useless. Why not `df.groupby('date')` and `df.groupby('int')` ? I wouldn't be surprised that those would be much faster. Also, the `dates` column does not contain dates. It contains numbers in range(1, 1500000). Finally, one of the significant differences is that ìnts` is in reality only the value 1 for about 1.5M records.

Comment: For some reason I cannot edit my previous comment but it contains a mistake. I misread the code and dates column does contain dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are creating a whole new list of values to group by, and passing through a python function to do it, instead of letting pandas just group on your values.

this means you're copying a whole lot of data around, and also each time converting between numpy's native datetime64 and python datetime object (which has multiple fields)

try this:

```py
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from timeit import timeit

d = dt.datetime(year=2019, month=1, day=1)
dates = [d for x in range(1,15000)]
ints = [1 for x in range(1,15000)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'int': ints})


print(timeit(lambda: df.groupby(by=[df.date.map(lambda x: x)]), number=100))
print(timeit(lambda: df.groupby(by=[df.int.map(lambda x: x)]), number=100))
print()
print(timeit(lambda: df.groupby('date'), number=100))
print(timeit(lambda: df.groupby('int'), number=100))
```

Output (on my machine...) (still shows some advantage for ints, but same order of magnitude):

```
4.080989988165176
0.7051316870900939

0.04927755465217576
0.03545470909939513
```

Comment: @ApplePie try `print(df['date'])`, you'll see `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

Comment: Thanks for that.  I wanted to be able to use `map` so I could perform group on a function of the date.  Specifically, I would like to group by things like week of the year.

Comment: I see I should have been using something like `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='w'))`